# Access To Internal Website DNS Settings

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, iis

We can access our IIS website on our server from any external computer (ie over the internet) but not internally from inside our network.

I assume I need to add a WWW A record in the dns records for our internal computers to access the website.

Our active directory is ad.ourwebsite.co.nz

However when I add the www record it wont let me change the FQDN. so I end up with www.ad.ourwebsite.co.nz when I am expecting to somehow set www.ourwebsite.co.nz

How do I amend the A record correctly?   Or do I need to create a new zone?

Using IIS on Windows Server 2016

Comment: If the two domains are different then it is probably not a DNS issue. You can easily check this by using `nslookup` to query the website address from inside and outside the network. If the IPs are the same and it works externally then it is not a DNS issue. Instead, it sounds like you are hosting your website on-premise and you actually have a NAT hairpin issue on your firewall/router which means you can’t access your “public” website from the same network it is connected to. You can either fix the NAT issue or create a split-dns setup so internal PCs get an internal server IP instead.

Comment: @Appleoddity Yes the website is hosted on premise.  When I run nslookup externally i get the correct ip address of the router.  However when I run nslookup on our internal domain I get: *** UnKnown can't find www.ourwebsite.co.nz: Query refused

Comment: The only think I have for NAT on my router is a setting of either cone or symmetric.

Comment: Then you will have to identify what DNS server you are querying (nslookup tells you) and fix the DNS server. It shouldn’t be doing that and is not properly forwarding the requests. The domain names are different so there is a problem in the DNS server configuration, not a need to create a new zone.